# Use a dynamic input from file

Tags: python, file, input, graph, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a graph from the below points:

```
edges = [
('X', 'A', 7),
('X', 'B', 2),
('X', 'C', 3),
('X', 'E', 4),
('A', 'B', 3),
('A', 'D', 4),
('B', 'D', 4),
('B', 'H', 5),
('C', 'L', 2)
]
```

where the first element in each line works as a source point, the second element works as a destination and the third point works as a distance between the 2 points.
Example - In first line X is the source, A is the destination and 7 is the weight of the edges between the 2 nodes.
When I use this directly in the code, I get the required graph.
However, I have to take the input from an external text file and use it in the code where the input will be like

```
A / B / 3
A / D / 4
B / D / 4
B / H / 5
C / L / 2
```

This is the code that we have used till now:-

```
from collections import defaultdictclass Graph():
def __init__(self):
self.edges = defaultdict(list)
self.weights = {}
def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, weight):
self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
self.weights[(from_node, to_node)] = weight
self.weights[(to_node, from_node)] = weight
graph = Graph()
edges = [
('X', 'A', 7),
('X', 'B', 2),
('X', 'C', 3),
('X', 'E', 4),
('A', 'B', 3),
('A', 'D', 4),
('B', 'D', 4),
('B', 'H', 5),
('C', 'L', 2),
]
for edge in edges:
graph.add_edge(*edge)
```

So, I want some clarification on how to add the edges from the input text file and use it in our python code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a text file called `test.txt` with the following content.

```
A / B / 3
A / D / 4
B / D / 4
B / H / 5
C / L / 2
```

Now, we just read this file line by line and split by the character `/` and put the result in a `3-tuple` and each `3-tuple` will be appended to an array called `edges`.

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

edges = []
for line in lines:
    t = line.strip().split(' / ')
    s = (*tuple(t[:-1]),int(t[2]))
    edges.append(s)
print(edges)
```

which yields the following output.

```py
[('A', 'B', 3), ('A', 'D', 4), ('B', 'D', 4), ('B', 'H', 5),('C', 'L', 2)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the third tuple eg., 3,4 ,4 as integer and then add it to edges

Comment: yes, see my updated answer.